# Does $\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{j}{a}\binom{k}{b}\binom{n-j-k}{c}=\binom{n+1}{a+b+c+2}?$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I'm working on a problem,

> (a) Let $a,b,n\geq1$ with $a+b\leq n$. By considering choosing $a+b+1$ numbers from the set $\{0,1,...,n\}$, and the possibilities for the number in position $a+1$ when the chosen numbers are listed in increasing order, show that $$\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}.$$
>
> (b) Hence, or otherwise, express $$\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{j}{a}\binom{k}{b}\binom{n-j-k}{c},$$ where $a+b+c\leq n$, as a single binomial coefficient.

Does the following argument make sense for (b)? (I leave a certain amount implicit.)

> Let \begin{align} 
> & j && \text{ be the } (a+1)^\text{th} && \text{number chosen}, \\ 
> & j+1+k && \text{ be the } (a+1)+(b+1)=(a+b+2)^\text{th} && \text{number chosen;}
> \end{align}
> Then there are \begin{align}
> & \binom{j}{a} && \text{ways of choosing the first $a$ numbers from } [0,j-1], \\
> & \binom{k}{b} && \text{ways of choosing the next $b$ numbers from } [j+1,j+k], \\
> & \binom{n-j-k}{c} && \text{ways of choosing the next $c$ numbers from } [j+1+k,n];
> \end{align}
> therefore the given expression is equal to $$\binom{n+1}{a+b+c+2}.$$

Comment: Two thumbs up! Looks alright!

Comment: Pretty sure the sum should require $j+k \leq n$, as otherwise the negative terms will get you back away from the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also derive a closed formula of the double sum by applying the identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{a}\binom{n-k}{b}=\binom{n+1}{a+b+1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
twice.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{j}{a}\binom{k}{b}\binom{n-j-k}{c}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{j}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{k}{b}\binom{(n-j)-k}{c}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{j}{a}\binom{n-j+1}{b+c+1}\tag{$\to$ (1)}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\binom{j}{a}\binom{(n+1)-j}{b+c+1}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n+2}{a+b+c+2}}\tag{$\to$ (1)}\\
> \end{align*}
> and observe that lower and upper index of the result have a summand $2$.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we set the upper limit of the inner sum to $n-j$ since the upper index of $\binom{n-j-k}{c}$ is non-negative.
- In (3) we make a rearrangement as preparation to apply (1).
- In (4) we set the upper limit of the sum to $n+1$ which does not change the sum, since $\binom{0}{b+c+1}=0$. We observe we can apply (1) again.